# If else doesn't work in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, if-statement

I have two stored procedures to select and insert values.When I choose an item from Listbox and click the add button, the code calls SP$select. Then a new Form appears and I give the data into the textbox. When I click save button, SP$insert works. But all the data can be only inserted into the first(Base) column. When I do all actions in SP$insert (select and insert) then it doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

**Procedure 1  [SP$select]**

```
use env
go

create proc [SP$select](
@p2 nvarchar(20),
@debug bit = 0)
as
begin
  set nocount on

    begin try
      if @p2='User Name'
        begin
            SELECT user_name FROM env.dbo.Base 
        end 

      else if @p2='Serial Number'
        begin
            SELECT ser_num FROM env.dbo.Base 
        end
    end try

    begin catch
     IF @debug = 1
       throw;
    end catch
end
set nocount off
go
```

**Procedure 2  [SP$insert]**

```
use env
go
create proc [SP$insert](
@p1 nvarchar(100),
@id int output,
@debug bit = 0)
as
begin
  set nocount on

    begin try
      if exists(select user_name from env.dbo.Base)
        begin
            INSERT INTO envanter.dbo.Base(user_name) VALUES (@p1)
            SELECT @id = @@IDENTITY
        end

      else if exists(select ser_num from env.dbo.Base)
        begin
            INSERT INTO env.dbo.Base(ser_num) VALUES (@p1)
            SELECT @id = @@IDENTITY
        end  
    end try

    begin catch
      if @debug = 1
        throw;
    end catch
set nocount off
end
go
```

Comment: your sql seems to be ok i think your call to SP$insert is wrong would you like to add your C# code as well ??

Comment: I think you are looking for the `CASE` expression in your [SP$select]

Comment: I have edited the question and added the calling in C#.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
use env
go
  create proc [SP$insert](
  @p1 nvarchar(100),
  @id int output,
  @debug bit = 0)
as
begin
   set nocount on

begin try
  if exists(select user_name from env.dbo.Base)
    begin
        INSERT INTO envanter.dbo.Base(user_name) VALUES (@p1)
        SELECT @id = @@IDENTITY
    end

  if exists(select ser_num from env.dbo.Base)
    begin
        INSERT INTO env.dbo.Base(ser_num) VALUES (@p1)
        SELECT @id = @@IDENTITY
    end  
end try

begin catch
  if @debug = 1
    throw;
end catch
set nocount off
end
go
```

Comment: Wenn I don't use else statement, the value is inserted into the both column.

Comment: i don't know what your exact scenario is ?? Would you like to elaborate it little bit more ?

Comment: @AftabAhmet I have in Form1 a listbox,that I choose randomly an item from it and a button for adding the values into the db. Wenn I click add button, the data calls from db and opens a new Form(Form2). In Form2 I have a Textbox and save button. I enter the data into the Textbox and click the save button to insert the selected value.That's all.

Comment: I have tried this in a stored proc(SP$insert) but it doesn't work. It seems so:                                             begin try
if @p2='User Name'
begin
SELECT user_name FROM env.dbo.Base WHERE user_name=@p2
if exists(select user_name from env.dbo.Base WHERE user_name=@p2)
INSERT INTO env.dbo.Base(user_name) VALUES (@p1)
SELECT @id = @@IDENTITY
end

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here. If there is at least one row on table Base the statement "if exists(select user_name from env.dbo.Base)" whill always be TRUE regardless of whether the user_name value is null or not, therefore **the "else if" part will never happen**.

Comment: Then what do you suggest instead of this? I just want to call and insert the data into the db, that I choose randomly from listbox.